# load svg file in esri map in arcgis android sdk

Tags: android, svg, sdk

How to load `.svg` file in Esri map android sdk version 10.2.9?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here are not only expected to thoroughly describe the problem, they are also expected to show effort towards solving it. For coding questions,  this means providing a code snippet representing your best effort.

Comment: Explain what you have done till now, what you expect and what error you are getting, so that the problem can be better diagnosed.

Comment: I have setup mapview and in that i have loaded the tpk file for offline purpose. I have added .tif file through raster layer.

And now i need to add .svg file and i don't know is there any way to load the .svg file in arcgis android sdk.

The raster layer doesn't load svg file.

In arcgis javascript i load the svg file using MapImageLayer and in android there is not such class to load svg.

can you help me to load svg file.